# How supervised or unsupervised machine learning algorithms get better over new datasets

Tags: machine-learning

Using [this Coursera's course about machine learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/welcome), I learned some things about [supervised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) and [unsupervised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning) algorithms.

And from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning#Overview) I've read that machine learning is "to get better performance/P at tasks/T with each task being done, that is experience/E".

Now, in those algorithms what I see is that they give it a set of data (either pre-labeled for supervised algorithms, or not for the other one) and the algorithms try to figure out the data and generate some output.

But I truly fail to find out WHERE and HOW in the process those algorithms BECOME BETTER with each new dataset they receive.

I really appreciate any help here. Did I miss something about machine learning? Without the **getting-better-with-each-new-dataset** part, how are these algorithms different from normal programs we write with a huge amount of conditional clauses and loops?

Answer (score 4):

The Coursera course only covers "batch" or "offline" methods for machine learning. In batch methods you train the model once, and then use the trained model as a static resource. What you are looking for are [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning) machine learning methods. Typically this involves finding an algorithm where the new data can be combined with the existing model to generate a new, improved model, but without simply tossing the new data into the same pot with the old data, and re-training from scratch.